# Terminal format

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

Every time I go into terminal and open a new window, it shows an extra line "teehee" and then allows me to perform another command.

Is there a way to edit this?

[image]

Comment: Whats the output of  `grep -n 'teehee' ~/.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc`?

Comment: there is none, I deleted the echo line in the bashrc file

Comment: Use `grep -RI teehee ~ /etc 2>/dev/null` to find all files under your home dir and under `/etc` containing that string. `-R` means recurse in subdirs, `-I` means ignore binaries, `2>/dev/null` means ignore messages about files you can't read.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like someone has edited your ~/.bashrc file (assuming that you are using the bash shell) and included a line

I suggest that you edit this file `nano ~/.bashrc` and look for a line like `echo teehee`. If you find such a line prefix it with a hash ("#") character to turn it into a comment.

If your .bashrc file has been edited in this way, your account has probably been compromised and other changes may have been made, passwords may have been compromised etc.

Comment: In that case, a fresh Ubuntu reinstall is the recommended solution, or is  it an exaggerated measure?

Comment: Changing password first would be better. If someone persists in doing this mischief, reinstall probably is the best option.  If it's someone from the family/friends/colleagues  and has physical access to the machine, one probably should get into habit of locking the screen

Comment: If you didn't put that string there, I would suggest a clean reinstall, and also a more thorough analysis of what might have been compromised: passwords stored by web browsers, email readers, ssh keys, GPG keys, the lot. If you did put the string there somehow, maybe you just didn't remove it properly.